# NoMethodError: undefined method. With if else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

in my home_controller.rb I have this

```
  def followed_movies
    @movies = current_user.followed_movies
                         .limit(12)
                         .order('movies.created_at DESC NULLS LAST').decorate
  end

  def subscriptions
    @movies = if followed_movies.any?
               followed_movies
             else
               recommended
             end
  end
```

but sometime I have this kind of issue:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `followed_movies' for nil:NilClass
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:35:in `followed_movies'
    .includes(:screen, :online_links)
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:41:in `subscriptions'
    @movies = if followed_movies.any?
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you..

```
def subscriptions 
    if current_user.followed_movies.present? 
        @movies = followed_movies 
    else 
        @movies = recommended 
    end 
 end
```

**Or**
use **present?**

present? is a Rails method from ActiveSupport

any? is pure Ruby A few important points:

```
nil.any? # => NoMethodError: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
 nil.present? # => false 
[""].any? && [""].present? # => true 
[""].any? &:present? # => false
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are having this issue occasionally and not every time, that means that sometimes `current_user` is `nil` (no user logged in) when `followed_movies` is called.

The controller should either check for the user being logged in before running the action, or you can change `followed_movies` method to check if `current_user` is `nil`.

```rb
  def followed_movies
    @movies = 
      if current_user.present?
        current_user.followed_movies
                    .limit(12)
                    .order('movies.created_at DESC NULLS LAST')
                    .decorate
      else
        []
      end
  end
```

If you want to just have the methods work whether or not variables are nil, use the safe navigation operator `&.`. `&.` will return `nil` if the method is called on a nil object.

```rb
  def followed_movies
    @movies = current_user&.followed_movies
                          &.limit(12)
                          &.order('movies.created_at DESC NULLS LAST')
                          &.decorate
  end

  def subscriptions
    @movies = if followed_movies&.any?
               followed_movies
             else
               recommended
             end
  end
```

With the methods written like this, if `followed_movies` will be `nil` `current_user` is `nil`, so when called in `subscriptions` you'll get `recommended`.

Comment: You shouldn't encourage people to do this (`current_user&.followed_movies&.limit(12)&.order('movies.created_at DESC NULLS LAST')&.decorate`) kind of things.

Comment: I'm always open to improving my coding standards, so please explain your comment. I'm guessing you don't like my use of the safe navigator operator? I generally prefer to check if an object is present if it might be nil, but I don't see anything wrong with using safe navigator instead.